# API Key Undefined in Axios

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I literally tried fetch and switch to axios to see what was wrong and still says my API key is undefined

```
`import axios from "axios";

const apiKey = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;

console.log(apiKey);

axios
  .post(
    "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions",
    {
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [{ role: "user", content: "Say this is a test!" }],
      temperature: 0.7,
    },
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
      },
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data.choices[0].message.content);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // console.log(error);
  });
`
```

I have my .env file on my root and I copied the API key into there

So it's `OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-wfwwfewfewf`

But when I console log the API key it keeps saying undefined?

I have both axios and openai installed in my package.json so I don't understand why it's not reading my API key properly.

I even tried pasting my code into chatgpt and says it sees no errors?

Answer (score 0):

In React you have to define your api key with prefix `REACT_APP`
In your `.env` file change your environment variable name as `REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY="Your_api_key"` and use it in your react file as `const apiKey = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;`

> make sure that your have created the `.env` file in the root of your react app

Comment: that didn't work. What if I used fetch instead?

Comment: have you restarted your react server after modifying environment variable?also try to print  your environment variable in react and ensure we get the value of that environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add double quotes "YOUR_API_KEY". And use REACT_APP_ before your varialbe.